# how do i add DNS record for a web service running on 8080 port on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, port

I have a web service running on aws under the following URL http://"54.194.164.164:8080"/webapi and the instance is associated with an Elastic IP 54.194.164.164. Now i want to add a DNS record so that i can access this easily like htttp://demo.mydomain.com/webapi.

what i have done so far is, i have added an A record called demo.mudomain.com to 54.194.164.164 in the  Godaddy DNS console but still i cant access demo.mydomain.com/webapi.

Can you please guide me what i have to do where i can access the web service easily as demo.mydomain.com/webapi

Thanks 
saththiyan

Comment: You can't use DNS to change default ports. HTTP has default port 80, so you can't rewire it to 8080 via DNS.

Comment: Either call it via `http://demo.mydomain.com:8080/webapi` or use some redirector service, **which needs to run on port 80**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. DNS maps names to IP addresses but not ports.

If you are going to access HTTP at an address it has to be:

1. Bound to the default port (80) if you don't want to specify the port.
2. Specified in the URL if it is a different port.

If you are trying to do this for an "easier" address you'll have to use port 80. If that is used by something else you are stuck with nominating a specific port.

You could consider assigning another ip address and setting up an address like `api.mydomain.com` to point to it. That way you could use `http://api.mydomain.com/webapi` by binding the API to that address rather than `http://demo.mydomain.com` which you are presumably using for something else.